# How to Read Byte Array of H.264 frames into EMGUCV

Tags: vb.net, opencv, h.264, emgucv

This is my first Question to SO so please excuse while i try and provide the correct information.

I Have a video capture card in a PC Running windows 7 (I have been told that the card cannot run on W10 or later but im yet to try that)

It seems to be a HV6000IE series DVR card, I have the SDK for it.

The Card Manufacturer seems to have gone under years ago so i cannot get support from them, I have a test app of theirs and the card works and gives video in their test app

I have been pulling my hair out for a good 2 weeks now trying to get an image out of it!

I have managed to connect to the Card via its DLL and can get information that im expecting to my queries, the SDK is wrong in many places but between that and the .h files i have managed to overcome a lot of the issues talking to it.

the card can provide an Original uncompressed image but i cannot get this to give me any data, i am not sure what the issue is with this approach but i guess that's a separate question.

It can also provide a stream of what seems to be H.264 encoded frames from what i can tell, and that's what Im trying to use at the moment (being the only remotely sensible image data i can get from the card).

this is the data from the first frame dumped to a file:
[Data Dump of first frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueFGS.png)

I have Byte Arrays coming in for each frame, some are I Frames and some are P Frames.

If i can get the image to a Mat, then from there ill be fine, as i have a USB camera that I'm working with in EMGU, however USB is not an option for this machine. The software I'm writing needs to run on the existing hardware of the machine.

Im using VB.NET but I'm happy for a solution to be in C# i can work with either.

Ill start another question on the Uncompressed image option as all i need is an image from this camera, i don't mind how i get it, as long as it ends up in a Emgu.CV.ImageBox

Comment: ...can't you just use DirectShow? Practically all video capture-cards for Windows support DirectShow.

Comment: That would be nice but this one does not support it. It’s 8 channel mini pci-e form factor too, so not easy to just replace. It’s also on 5 machines that I need to get it working on.

Comment: Your data dump is not valid H.264 - the first four bytes look like an Access Unit Delimiter but the rest is garbled - you may not marshal the buffer correctly from C to VB.

I have been working with capture cards for a long time - professionally.
Even in a perfect world, with customer support etc - this is an uphill battle that can take month.

Now your SDK is written in C - I assume - and you want to use it from VB or C#.
Lot's of red flags here - sorry.

Comment: Thanks heaps Markus, your assumptions are correct C - VB, you have also confirmed my suspicions that this may be a bridge too far, I have many years development experience but very new to capture cards, I will have to look at replacing the card with something supported and easier